# having trouble loading default page of tomcat server

Tags: tomcat

I did following steps to install tomcat 7 on redhat. The VM (redhat) when I ping either ip of the machine or fqdn, the server is up and running.

```
1) downloaded/installed Java 7 (1.7.0_75)
2) set env variables JAVA_HOME,JRE_HOME,and PATH
3) downloaded/installed tomcat 7
4) started the server (./bin/startup.sh)
5) get proper messaged returned saying "Tomcat started"
6) checked catalina.out log file no exception is thrown 
7) from the log file, "INFO: Server startup in 3244 ms"
8) i hit http://hostname:8080 from a browser to get to default page of tomcat server
9) problem loading page both in chrome/FF
```

I ran "netstat -nap | grep 8080" to make sure a process is started listening port 8080 and PID returned matches with PID returned from "ps -ef | grep tomcat" command which I see footprint of a process ties to tomcat server.

I wonder what I did wrong...

Comment: what happens when you say http://localhost:8080/index.html?

Comment: @almas: I should have tried that first. :)  Thanks for reminding me however I still can't load the page... "This webpage is not available" from chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I had to enable port 8080 via iptables.